# ¿Cómo decodificar cadena en base64 con delphi?

Tags: delphi, base64

Necesito de su ayuda, pues he probado múltiples opciones y no logro encontrar la solución:
tengo esta

```
cadenaEnBase64="ewAiAEQAYQB0AGUAIgA6ACIAMQAxAC8AMAAzAC8AMgAwADIAMQAiACwAIgBJAGQAZQBuAHQAaQB0AHkAIgA6ACIAcwBmAHMAZgBqAGkAZgBuAGQAaQBmAGgAZABmADIANAA2ADQAMQAiACwAIgBEAGEAdABlAEUAcwAiADoAIgAwADEALwAxADIALwAyADAAMgAxACIALAAiAEQAYQB0AGUARQBMACIAOgAiADAAMQAvADEAMgAvADIAMAAyADIAIgAsACIAVABpAHAAbwBzAEwASQBDAEUATgBDAEkAQQAiADoAOQAsACIAQQBjAHQAaQB2AGUAIgA6AHQAcgB1AGUALAAiAEwAaQBjAGUAbgBzAGUAXwBOACIAOgAxADIANQAxAH0A"
```

deseo decodificarla a esto (este es el resultado):

```
{"Date":"11/03/2021","Identity":"sfsfjifndifhdf24641","DateEs":"01/12/2021","DateEL":"01/12/2022","TiposLICENCIA":9,"Active":true,"License_N":1251}
```

pueden probar el resultado en:   https://www.base64decode.org/

pero con Delphi 10.3 ni 7 he obtenido resultados, muestra solo la primera llave:

```
{
```

Ese es el único resultado que obtengo.

Comment: Pon tu código para verlo, edita tu pregunta y ponlo ahi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Respuesta rápida (y corta)

Utiliza esta función para decodificar la cadena:

```
uses
  System.NetEncoding;

function Base64ToString(EncodedString: string): string;
begin
  Result := TEncoding.Unicode.GetString(TNetEncoding.Base64.DecodeStringToBytes(EncodedString));
end;
```

Por ejemplo, así:

```
Memo2.Text := Base64ToString(Memo1.Text);
```

## Hablemos de Base64

Para comenzar, hay que tener siempre en cuenta que Base64 es, en esencia, un algoritmo de codificación que permite representar cualquier cosa que se encuentre en la memoria de la computadora utilizando caracteres ASCII. Es decir, se puede utilizar para codificar/decodificar cualquier bloque de información, no solo texto. Esto significa que, cuando se codifica texto, en realidad lo que se hace es codificar **la representación en memoria** de dicho texto.

De hecho, los algoritmos de codificación/decodificación en Base64 suelen trabajar con *[streams](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TStream)* o arreglos de bytes, ignorando por completo qué es lo que se encuentra representado en esos bytes.

### Base64 de cadenas de texto

Algunas personas, por comodidad, suelen crear rutinas para codificar/decodificar cadenas te texto que hacen uso de estos algoritmos. Al hacerlo, lo más común en tiempos modernos es utilizar UTF8 para representar la cadena antes de codificarla, de manera que se pueda representar cualquier caracter Unicode y, a la vez, mantener un tamaño mínimo en la memoria. Esto es más o menos un estándar de-facto (hasta donde sé, no está escrito en ninguna regla que deba hacerse de esa manera y, de hecho, no todos lo respetan).

Tomando en cuenta lo dicho hasta ahora, cae de su propio peso deducir que el resultado del proceso de codificación no será el mismo si lo aplicacmos sobre una cadena de texto con formato UTF8, que con UTF16, ASCII o ANSI, pues la misma cadena puede tener una distinta representación en memoria entre una y otra. De hecho, en el mundo Unicode, siempre tendrá una distinta representación entre UTF8/UTF16, pues en una el caracter de base ocupa 1 byte de memoria y en la otra ocupa 2.

Y sobra decir que cuándo se decodifica, ya que lo que se obtiene es un poco de bytes en memoria, si no se interpreta bajo la misma codificación, ocurrirán errores y al final se obtendrá una cadena distinta de la que se codificó. Esta es la situación que vemos en este caso.

Inspeccionando el resultado de decodificar la cadena que presentas, podemos ver que cada segundo byte es 0. Por ejemplo, ejecutándo este código en Delphi:

```
procedure TForm3.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bytes: TBytes;
  Str1, Str2: string;
begin
  Bytes := TNetEncoding.Base64.DecodeStringToBytes(Memo1.Text);
end;
```

Si ponemos un punto de parada, ejecutamos la línea de código y vemos la ventanita de variables locales, nos muestra algo como lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto rápidamente me hizo pensar que la cadena original tenía caracteres del alfabeto latino, representadas como UTF 16 (donde el segundo byte queda regularmente en 0).

Por eso, la rutina de la solución, directamente aplica esta codificación para re-interpretar los bytes como cadena, lo que nos devuelve el siguiente texto:

```
{"Date":"11/03/2021","Identity":"sfsfjifndifhdf24641","DateEs":"01/12/2021","DateEL":"01/12/2022","TiposLICENCIA":9,"Active":true,"License_N":1251}
```

## Mi recomendación:

Dicho todo esto, si tienes control sobre el lugar donde se realiza la codificación de la cadena original en base 64, lo más recomendable es codificar la representación en UTF8 de esta cadena. Si esta se realiza con Delphi, tan sencillo como llamar a:

```
  CadenaEnBase64 := TNetEncoding.Base64.Encode('cadena original');
```

Esto, como he dicho antes, es el estándar de facto de la red.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo probé y funciona perfecto, no tenía conocimiento sobre lo de utf16, UNICODE o mejor dicho cómo podria afectar la decodificación, ahora entiendo mucho mejor este tema!!!

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español.
En cuanto a tu pregunta, creo que estás teniendo problemas con la codificación, dado que la propia página que comentas no está haciendo correctamente la decodificación.

Por ejemplo, si pruebas en estas (aunque puedes encontrar más), con la cadena que has colocado, verás que el resultado en todas ellas es similar, pero no es el esperado por ti:

> ewAiAEQAYQB0AGUAIgA6ACIAMQAxAC8AMAAzAC8AMgAwADIAMQAiACwAIgBJAGQAZQBuAHQAaQB0AHkAIgA6ACIAcwBmAHMAZgBqAGkAZgBuAGQAaQBmAGgAZABmADIANAA2ADQAMQAiACwAIgBEAGEAdABlAEUAcwAiADoAIgAwADEALwAxADIALwAyADAAMgAxACIALAAiAEQAYQB0AGUARQBMACIAOgAiADAAMQAvADEAMgAvADIAMAAyADIAIgAsACIAVABpAHAAbwBzAEwASQBDAEUATgBDAEkAQQAiADoAOQAsACIAQQBjAHQAaQB2AGUAIgA6AHQAcgB1AGUALAAiAEwAaQBjAGUAbgBzAGUAXwBOACIAOgAxADIANQAxAH0A

- https://www.base64decode.org/
- https://www.base64decode.net/
- https://codebeautify.org/base64-decode

En el resultado aparecen el resultado correcto, pero intercalando caracteres incorrectos. Tiene pinta de que lo que estás enviando no está en la codificación correcta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si codificas la cadena con cualquiera de esas páginas, el resultado es similar en todas:

Cadena:

> {"Date":"11/03/2021","Identity":"sfsfjifndifhdf24641","DateEs":"01/12/2021","DateEL":"01/12/2022","TiposLICENCIA":9,"Active":true,"License_N":1251}

Cadena en Base64:

> eyJEYXRlIjoiMTEvMDMvMjAyMSIsIklkZW50aXR5Ijoic2ZzZmppZm5kaWZoZGYyNDY0MSIsIkRhdGVFcyI6IjAxLzEyLzIwMjEiLCJEYXRlRUwiOiIwMS8xMi8yMDIyIiwiVGlwb3NMSUNFTkNJQSI6OSwiQWN0aXZlIjp0cnVlLCJMaWNlbnNlX04iOjEyNTF9

Si esta misma cadena (la original) la codificas y decodificas con Delphi, obtendrás el resultado esperado. El código es simple, ya que Delphi posee una [unit para codificar/decodificar base64](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.NetEncoding.TBase64Encoding).

Con un cóodigo como este puedes codificarla y decodificarla:

```
uses
  System.NetEncoding;

procedure TForm3.Memo1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Codificar
  Memo2.Lines.Text := TBase64Encoding.Base64.Encode(Memo1.Lines.Text);
end;

procedure TForm3.Memo2Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Decodificar
  Memo3.Lines.Text := TBase64Encoding.Base64.Decode(Memo2.Lines.Text);
end;
```

Y el resultado es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo tanto deduzco que tienes un problema con la cadena inicial. Habría que saber de dónde la has obtenido o cómo se ha codificado.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, sí eso me parece muy extraño dos cosas: Priemro que al meter la cadena en base64 en la pagina que dejé en la pregunta incial sí me stá arrojando el resultado, pero el intentar hacerlo de las mil maneras en delphi no pude.